# Q nextquestion and check button in a car questionnaire

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a car questionnaire. I have some problems with the next question and veryfiy buttons.

Here is how my program works. I have 4 text files. First Questions(where are my all questions) , Second (first answer) , Second (second answer), Third(the third answer) and the last with the Correct answers

```
int answersNo;
int currentQuestion;
int totalNo;
bool[] Checked = new bool[26];
string contents;
int score;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalNo = 26;
        answersNo = 0;
        currentQuestion = 1;
        score = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                answerLabel[i, j] = new Label();
                answerLabel[i, j].Left = 50;
                answerLabel[i, j].AutoSize = false;
                answerLabel[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                answerLabel[i, j].Width = 500;
                answerLabel[i, j].Height = 45;
                answerLabel[i, j].Top = 200 +j * 50;
                answerLabel[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
                this.Controls.Add(answerLabel[i, j]);
            }

        label1.Text = question.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 0].Text = answer1.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 1].Text = answer2.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 2].Text = answer3.ReadLine();

        answerLabel[0, 0].Click += new EventHandler(answer1_Click);
        answerLabel[0, 1].Click += new EventHandler(answer2_Click);
        answerLabel[0, 2].Click += new EventHandler(answer3_Click);

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalNo; i++)
        {
            Checked[i] = false;
        }
```

}

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // the button which verifies if the answer is good
        {
            contents = goodAnswer.ReadToEnd();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if ( answerLabel[i, j].BackColor==Color.Yellow && contents.Contains(answerLabel[i, j].Text))
                    {
                        score++;
                        MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
                        nextQuestion();
                    }

                }
        }
```

and my function

```
public void nextQuestion()
    {
        if (answersNo < totalNo-1)
        {
            do
            {
                if (currentQuestion < totalNo)
                {
                    Checked[currentQuestion] = false;
                    currentQuestion++;

                }
                else
                    currentQuestion = 1;
            }
            while (Checked[currentQuestion] == true);

            label1.Text = question.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 0].Text = answer1.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 1].Text = answer2.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 2].Text = answer3.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have done it!");
        }

        answersNo++;
    }
```

I don't know how to verify the answer and to get to the next question if I press a button . ( We all know how the car questionnaires work).

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Does it not do what you expect, or is there a compile error?

Comment: it does not go to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: put a breakpoint in a method `button1_click` and launch application from Visual Studio in debug mode by pressing F5, debug step by step, no rush, see values of variables and think on each step.

If method has been called called there are three possible reasons to skip nextQuestion call:

```
if (answerLabel[i, j].BackColor == Color.Yellow 
     && contents.Contains(answerLabel[i, j].Text))
```

1. Color for the right answer entry is not Yellow
2. Answer is not present in `contents`
3. Answer is present in `contents` but different probably in one character/case/typo, so use

   ```
   String.Compare(contents, 
                  answerLabel[i, j].Text,
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
   ```

**Questions:**

1. What is `goodAnswer` variable, please show how it is initialized
2. Why you need `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`, it does nothing, you can just use `int i = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I have different text files with all the questions, the first answer, the second and the third, and another text file with the correct answers.

This is goodAnswer.

```
StreamReader goodAnswer = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\goodanswer.txt");
```

before to click the check button , I want that the answer chosen to be colored in yellow.ussualy when they are not pressed the answers are white.

and I want a function something ( to verify just the colored answer if it's correct)